# windows docker save - no space left on device

Tags: docker

I am using docker on windows. I installed docker following this link https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/. Then I built the image from https://github.com/floydhub/dl-docker

Now I want to save the image to my pc. This was the command I issued.

```
docker save -o c:/Users/Student/dl-docker-latest.tar 69b639351d9c
```

Then I got this error

```
Error response from daemon: write /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-export-757581070/3cb616a54d6bdbb8bb42a53a62b44de10eb7d7ea63b4b0a5038493175e7e12b3/layer.tar: no space left on device
```

Can someone tell me what is going on ? I have more than enough space on my pc and the image is only 8GB.

How do I get to this location from my terminal ?

> /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-export-757581070/3cb616a54d6bdbb8bb42a53a62b44de10eb7d7ea63b4b0a5038493175e7e12b3

I followed http://phutchins.com/blog/2017/01/04/fixing-docker-no-space-left-on-device/ and typed docker run --rm --privileged floydhub/dl-docker:cpu df -h
I guess I need to increase the size of docker

[image]

Comment: What device / file system is file on?  Is it a "tmpfs" file system?  Is there enough space in that file system?

Comment: Sorry I am new to docker. Do you mean the image file? Its in a VM and im not sure where it is. How can I increase the docker size?

Comment: I mean the place where docker is trying to write to.  As indicated by the error message!

Comment: oh sorry its in my c drive which has 329 GB left

Comment: oh wait if you meant the /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker..... then ill need to check. not sure how to get there. How do I get to that location from my terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that docker daemon uses its own way for export, import and build. So it may create a copy of the image temporarily. Which means if it s a 8GB image you may need additional space for the operation to work.

Docker for windows uses Hyper-V to create a Linux VM and runs docker inside it. There is default space allocated to it, so even though your laptop has space left the VM doesn't have.

So what's the solution.

**Try STDOUT instead of file**

```
docker save 69b639351d9c > c:/Users/Student/dl-docker-latest.tar
```

I have my doubts this would work, but worth a try

**Increase the VM Size**

Now I don't know if there a easier way for this. But you need to create the VM again with a bigger size

See the below issue for more details

https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/825

Or you can try resizing the existing disk using techniques mentioned in below article

http://derekmolloy.ie/resize-a-virtualbox-disk/